# how to create a histogram in matlab with required number of cells?

Tags: matlab, geometry, histogram

I am new in matlab and I am making a gremetric simulation with k = m2 and p = 1/5.
I have to generate 1000 random numbers and I must show them in a histogram with 15 number of cells. this is what I have so far:

```
K = 2;
P 1/5;
R = geornd(p,k,1000);
```

now I am trying to show these result in  a histogram with 15 cells but I dont know how to do it please help.

EDIT: 
to get the histogram I used:
`hist(Sc,15)`, and this is the results:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the help for hist? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html?refresh=true

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html tells you that you can specify the number of bins in the hist function `hist(data,nbins)`

Comment: @Benoit_11 I did look at that I could figure anything out.

Comment: @sed i dont think thats corrects. I will upload the picture.

Comment: @S.N you need to input 1D array to `hist` in order to get a single histogram. it seems like your input `Sc` is 2D and this is why you get multiple histograms.

Comment: @Shai do you think my Geometric simulation is correct? because instead of having 1000 numbers for r, I have 2000 numbers and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc for [geornd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/geornd.html), you need to provide the function with a probability parameter P (here 1/5) and a vector dictating the size of the output you want, so it looks like your K is not used correctly in this context.

If you want 1000 random values distributed according to geornd, you might want to use this instead:

```
R = geornd(0.2,[1 1000]); % P of 0.2 and array of 1 x 1000 numbers
hist(R,15)
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

If you do want do generate 2 distributions, then you can calculate them all at once and plot them separately:

```
R = geornd(0.2,[2 1000]);

% Plot 1st distribution:
hist(R(1,:),15)

Plot 2nd distribution:
hist(R(2,:),15)
```

Comment: and what is the K in this example? why my K is not used correctly?

Comment: please see my edited answer; hopefully this is what you want!

Comment: @S.N so is this what you were looking for?